# Add a click on QLineEdit

Tags: python, qt, qlineedit

I am working on set a click() event to QLineEdit, I already successfully did it. But I want to go back to Mainwindow when the QLine Edit is clicked because I need the data in Mainwindow to further process the data. But I failed to let it go back, neither nor to cite the Mainwindow as parent, I hope someone can point it out. Thank you so much.

```
MainWindow
{

...


self.tc = MyLineEdit(self.field[con.ConfigFields.VALUE])#self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(self.parent, -1, str(field[con.ConfigFields.VALUE]), pos=(x+220, y-3), size=(200, -1))

...

}


class MyLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent=MainWindow):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        #super(CustomQLineEidt, self).__init__()


    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.mouseseleted()

    def mouseseleted(self):
        print "here"
        MainWindow.mousePressEvent
```

Comment: Can you post more details on your MainWindow code? I am not able to understand what you mean by "I need the data in Mainwindow to further process the data. But I failed to let it go back, neither nor to cite the Mainwindow as parent"?

Comment: I meant once the QLineEdit is clicked, I will use some data from the variables of MainWindow and show it in other QTextEdit. So I need to process the data in MainWindow so I can use the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply call the `MainWindow` `mousePressEvent` and give it the `event` variable the line edit received

```
class MyLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parentWindow = parent

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print 'forwarding to the main window'
        self.parentWindow.mousePressEvent(event)
```

Or you can connect a signal from the line edit

```
class MyLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    mousePressed = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QMouseEvent)

    def __init__(self, value):

        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__(value)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print 'forwarding to the main window'
        self.mousePressed.emit(event)
```

Then just connect the signal in your main window where you created it

```
    self.tc = MyLineEdit(self.field[con.ConfigFields.VALUE])#self.tc = wx.TextCtrl(self.parent, -1, str(field[con.ConfigFields.VALUE]), pos=(x+220, y-3), size=(200, -1))
    self.tc.mousePressed[QtGui.QMouseEvent].connect(self.mousePressEvent)
```

Comment: Hi,David,Thank you, but I just tried it, but it doesn't work, first, I must put QtGui.QLineEdit instead of QLineEdit in the brackets, or there will a error. Second, there is no parent variable of MyLineEdit. So it can not forwarding to the main window.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try the second one if you can't give the `QLineEdit` a parent.

Comment: File "/Users/cvorg/vel/VEL Programmer/Aug_29th.py", line 1486, in MyLineEdit
    mousePressed = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtCore.QMouseEvent)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QMouseEvent'

Comment: Oops that was supposed to be QtGui.QMouseEvent. The answer is updated

Comment: File "/Users/cvorg/vel/VEL Programmer/Aug_29th.py", line 1046, in setupwintabGrid
    self.tc.mousePressed[QtGui.QMouseEvent].connect(self.mousePressEvent)
AttributeError: 'MyLineEdit' object has no attribute 'mousePressed'

Comment: add the line `mousePressed = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QMouseEvent)` to your `MyLineEdit`... if your getting an error still you didn't do something right...

Answer (score 5):

I use the following to connect any method as the callback for a click event:

```
class ClickableLineEdit(QLineEdit):
    clicked = pyqtSignal() # signal when the text entry is left clicked

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton: self.clicked.emit()
        else: super().mousePressEvent(event)
```

To use:

```
textbox = ClickableLineEdit('Default text')
textbox.clicked.connect(someMethod)
```

Specifically for the op:

```
self.tc = ClickableLineEdit(self.field[con.ConfigFields.VALUE])
self.tc.clicked.connect(self.mouseseleted)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to do onClick for QLineEdits

```
class MyLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    def focusInEvent(self, e):
        try:
            self.CallBack(*self.CallBackArgs)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        super().focusInEvent(e)

    def SetCallBack(self, callBack):
        self.CallBack = callBack
        self.IsCallBack = True
        self.CallBackArgs = []

    def SetCallBackArgs(self, args):
        self.CallBackArgs = args
```

and in my MainGUI:

```
class MainGUI(..):

    def __init__(...):
        ....
        self.input = MyLineEdit()
        self.input.SetCallBack(self.Test)
        self.input.SetCallBackArgs(['value', 'test'])
        ...

    def Test(self, value, test):
        print('in Test', value, test)
```